# How to change the class behavior using mock?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, unit-testing

For example, I have the following logic in my Django test:

```
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase, APIClient
import unittest
from mock import patch
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
from rest_framework import status
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class APITest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient(enforce_csrf_checks=False)
        self.user = User.objects.create_user('test_user', 'test_user@test.com', 'password')
        self.user.save()

    def test_auth_get(self):
        with patch('app.views.RabbitMq.run_rabbitmq'):
            self.client.login(username='test_user', password='password')
            self.client.force_authenticate(user=self.user)
            response = self.client.get(reverse('user-list'), format='json')
            print response
            self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

according to this urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from rest_framework import routers
from views import UserViewSet, GroupViewSet

router = routers.SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'groups', GroupViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),
]
```

and I want to mock run_rabbitmq in views.py:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, Group
import pika
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets
from serializers import UserSerializer, GroupSerializer

class RabbitMq:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def run_rabbitmq(self):
        connection = pika.BlockingConnection(pika.ConnectionParameters('localhost'))
        channel = connection.channel()
        channel.queue_declare(queue='test')
        channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='test', body='Hello World!')
        connection.close()

def rabbitmq_wrap(OriginalClass):
    orig_init = OriginalClass.__init__
    def __init__(self, *args, **kws):
        rabbit = RabbitMq()
        rabbit.run_rabbitmq()
        orig_init(self, *args, **kws)

    OriginalClass.__init__ = __init__
    return OriginalClass

@rabbitmq_wrap
class Record:
    def __init__(self):
        pass # here is the logic of writing to database

class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet, Rabbitmq):
    record = Record()

    queryset = User.objects.all().order_by('-date_joined')
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class GroupViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Group.objects.all()
    serializer_class = GroupSerializer

def my_view(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Hello!</h1>')
```

in a way that it just does nothing. Neither returns nor processes something, just nothing (e.g. sending SMS messages while testing etc.), like it only has a "pass" in the body.

Having [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#where-to-patch) how to mock instance inside of the decorator?

Comment: The key focus is on @patch decorator - does it work in general in a way I want or not and what should I do with it to run it to achieve the right behavior?

Comment: @MartijnPieters I've rewritten the question, may you unblock it?

Comment: It was reopened by community vote already. Thanks for updating it!

Comment: Your code, as posted, just works. You patched the right object, the `rabbit` local variable in the decorator not is a `MagicMock` instance, but the `rabbit.run_rabbitmq()` call *is*.